# Connection lost after query runs for few minutes in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4 and PostGIS 1.5. What I'm trying to do is INSERT data from one table to another (but not strictly the same data). For each column, a few queries are run and there are a total of 50143 rows stored in the table. But the query is quite resource-heavy: after the query has run for a few minutes, the connection is lost. Its happening about 21-22k MS into the execution of the query, after which I have to start the DBMS manually again. How should I go about solving this issue?

The error message is as follows:

```
 [Err] server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

Additionally, here is the psql error log:

```
2013-07-03 05:33:06 AZOST HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2013-07-03 05:33:06 AZOST WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2013-07-03 05:33:06 AZOST DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
```

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL logs for anything relevant.

Comment: Go further back in the logs than that, that is after-effects of the real error. Also, use the `{}` (four space indent) button so the logs aren't line-wrapped.

Comment: Also, is Linux's memory overcommit disabled? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html#LINUX-MEMORY-OVERCOMMIT

Comment: Is there a  connection or query timeout setting somewhere in postgis?

Answer (score 2):

My guess, reading your problem, is that you are hitting out of memory issues.  Craig's suggestion to turn off overcommit is a good one.  You may also need to reduce `work_mem` if this is a big query.  This may slow down your query but it will free up memory.  `work_mem` is per operation so a query can use many times that setting.

Another possibility is you are hitting some sort of bug in a C-language module in PostgreSQL.  If this is the case, try updating to the latest version of PostGIS etc.

Comment: I repeatedly got this error when running pg_restore and after bumping the memory on the receiving end (a cloud machine, 8GB -> 52GB) the error did not return. I noticed the peak memory consumption while running the successful pg_restore on the 52GB machine was roughly 22GB.